# Why I get a Remote Management popup on a MacBook?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

I just bought a MacBook Pro from someone on Craigslist. When going through the set up process, I get a popup titled "Remote Management" and "Google can automatically configure your computer." Why am I getting this? How do I get rid of this so I can start using my MacBook?

Comment: Companies register with Apple and Apple provides them a procurement identifier code. When the company purchases Mac's and mobile devices those devices will be assigned to the company and during the setup process and will phone home to Apple who then redirects the device to the companies MDM (Mobile Device Management) servers. The device auto-enrolls and a certificate and MDM Configuration Profile are installed.  Then the MDM server can remotely manage the device. It is either a stolen Google employee Mac or Google failed to remove it from their Apple Business account.

Comment: Thanks @JamesBrickley! This person isn't answering their phone, which is a Text Now number and he wore a mask during the exchange, which was cash. Am I just screwed and lost out on $1200? Or is there something I can do to make this useable?

Comment: Morally and legally it is stolen property. You could let it enroll. That would let internal Google IT know it’s online. Then try calling Google. Here’s their office locations and switchboard numbers. Tell them you may have purchased a Mac stolen from an employee. https://about.google/intl/in/locations

Comment: If it’s not stolen maybe they can remove it from Apple Business so it becomes your property.